# How to concatenate exiting data present in a variable with new data in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-18

I was wondering is there a way to concatenate a variable with incoming data. I currently have a table called TABLE-A with address variable which already has data in it. There is a front-end application through which users input information into this table. I was wondering is there a way to concatenate new incoming information with existing information. Below is the example.

Example:

TABLE-A (ORIGINAL VIEW)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | 12 DOWNING STREET |

TABLE-A (EXPECTED VIEW AFTER USER ENTERS NEW INFORMATION)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | 12 DOWNING STREET; 24 WASHINGTON SQUARE PARK; |

In the expected view '24 WASHINGTON SQUARE PARK' is the new address user enters and in the table we are capturing it and adding it to the existing address '12 DOWNING STREET'. I tried to create a trigger but our front end is not accepting a table with triggers enabled. So triggers are not an option.

It would be great if someone could provide any type of solutions.

Thanks,
Banana19

Comment: `SELECT ColumnB + '; ' + @Variable + ';'` ... or `UPDATE TableA SET ColumnB = ColumnB + '; ' + @Variable + ';' WHERE ColumnA = 'condition'`

Comment: Usually it's not a good idea to store more than one "part" of data per column. Why do you need to concat stuff?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: @siggemannen We are trying to capture all the addresses the business has for the person named John. So multiple businesses come to the front-end application and enters the address they have, and our goal is to capture all the addresses they have in the address column. Hence the concatenation.

Comment: First, a front end cannot decide on how backend works. Second, it is not a good idea to store data in such a way. Third, if you don't care about former two, then you can use + operator to concatenate data in an update command.

Comment: Great, i thought so. Now, let's say a business enter a ";" into part of the address. And this goes on for a while. Would you be able to reparse out the individual addresses? For this and other reason, what you should do is some sort of history table which stores previous addresses

Comment: Why don't you simply follow normalization rules in an RDBMS and store that information in a 1-to-many fashion.

Comment: Why not normalize into separate tables? Storing multiple pieces of data in a single column is a really bad idea.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Unfortunately the POWERAPP has that issue of throwing error whenever a backend SQL table has triggers enabled. This is a big hole in POWERAPP which they are looking into it to fix for the upcoming releases.

Comment: @siggemannen I've already suggested a history table. Hopefully my superior considers that. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use a front end that has such enforcement on backend. (I wouldn't do it with trigger either, as I said simply use relations and 1-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update anything in database, just use update (you can add additional spaces/delimiters in SET part):

```
UPDATE TABLE-A SET [COLUMN B] = [COLUMN B] + NEW INFORMATION
WHERE [COLUMN A] = USER
```

But if the user deletes something through UI, it will be a problem. In my opinion, the approach should be different here. If it is a one column in database, UI should return a full line of current adresses. So you will need update a respective row with a line from UI without any manipulations.

Or there is another way - to keep all adresses separately. The structure will be like that:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | 12 DOWNING STREET |
| JOHN | 24 WASHINGTON SQUARE PARK |

It is easy to manage data in such format (insert/update/delete/select/search).